# Подгрузка связных данных в EF Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Как через UserManager можно подгрузить пользователя с связными данными? есть:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

Если получать пользователя через UserManager, то Profile не подгружается. Как можно это решить, кроме как так:

```
await _dbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Profile).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == User.Identity.Name)
```

Comment: `UserProfile` - это класс данных пользователя для представлений, как я понимаю? Если так, то его стоит хранить в отдельной таблице, реализовав собственный [репозиторий](https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/11.php) и тянуть дополнительным запросом.
Так вы отделите единицу регистрации от единицы пользователя.